# sortBy a column of RDD in Spark

Tags: scala, sorting, apache-spark

I have an RDD points of type `[(Double, Double)]` and I have to iteratively sort it with respect to each column. The column with which to sort is stored in variable '`axis`' and is evaluated as 0 or 1 based on whether the RDD is to be sorted by the 1st column or 2nd one. I tried the following but none of it seems to work:

```
    val sorted = points.sortBy(p => p._(axis))
```

or,

```
    val sorted = points.sortBy(_(axis))
```

I get the following error: `Error:(18, 39) (Double, Double) does not take parameters`
Error occurred in an application involving default arguments.

Any help in this regard would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `productElement` method to access dynamically to an element of a tuple.

The only problem is that this method returns an `Any`, so you need to convert it to `Double` (and to do so, you need first to convert `Any` to `String`)

Try this:

```
points.sortBy(_.productElement(axis).toString.toDouble)
```

**EXAMPLE**

**input**

```
points.foreach(println)
(0,1)
(1,0)
```

**AXIS = 1**

```
scala> val axis= 1
axis: Int = 1

scala> points.sortBy(_.productElement(axis).toString.toDouble)
res19: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[16] at sortBy at <console>:28

scala> res19.foreach(println)
(1,0)
(0,1)
```

**AXIS = 0**

```
scala> val axis= 0
axis: Int = 0

scala> points.sortBy(_.productElement(axis).toString.toDouble)
res24: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, Int)] = MapPartitionsRDD[26] at sortBy at <console>:28

scala> res24.foreach(println)
(0,1)
(1,0)
```

Comment: `.toString.toDouble`? If the value is a `Double` (which it's guaranteed to be in this case), it's much slower than necessary; if it's not, it'll likely throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
  def sortValue(axis: Int)(p: (Double, Double)) = if (axis == 0) p._1 else p._2

  val sorted = points.sortBy(p => sortValue(axis)(p))
```